# A symmetrical die is thrown independently 7 times, what is the probability that the sum of the faces is 14?

Tags: probability, generating-functions, dice

[A 3 dice version has been asked and answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895803/if-a-fair-die-is-thrown-three-times-what-is-the-probability-that-the-sum-of-the).

However it is much simpler to count when you only throw the dice 3 times.

I am interested in a solution using probability generating functions (PGF). (Would be nice to see a counting one too).

I got that the PGF of one throw is:
$$\frac16\left(s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5+s^6\right)=\frac16s\left(1+s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5\right).$$
Hence the PGF of 7 independent throws is:
$$\frac1{6^7}s^7\left(1+s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5\right)^7.$$
However I do not know where to take it from here.

Comment: Essentially, a probability generating function is one which is of the form $\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}P(Y=y)s^y$. So you would need to take the $k_th$ derivative of the _pgf_ at s=0 and divide this by $k!$ to get the probability $P(Y=k)$. Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710047/probability-generating-function-to-probability-mass-function

Comment: I know that's what you need to find, however it's an ugly one to differentiate (no nice general formula). In the link to the previous post that I put at the beginning of this question, the second solution seems to find the answer in a neat way. I just don't understand why he has $x^9$ instead of $x^3$ and do not understand why he equates it with 25. I was trying to apply a similar approach here as well.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the link! The $[x^9]$ notation is essentially saying we find the coefficient that goes with $x^9$ in our ugly looking _pgf_. Let me see if I can come up with an answer using the compositions in my answer!

Comment: Sorry I took so long, is that good? Technically you could get the full marginal distribution for the total rolled in 7 rolls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f(s) = \frac{1}{6^7}s^7{(1+s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5)}^7
$$
We want to find the coefficient of $s^{14}$ when $f(s)$ is expanded.  One way to do this is to notice that $1 + s + s^2 + \dots + s^5$ is the sum of a geometric series, for which we have a formula.
$$\begin{align}
f(s) &= \frac{1}{6^7} s^7 \left( \frac{1-s^6}{1-s} \right) ^7 \\
&=  \frac{1}{6^7} s^7 \; (1-s^6)^7 \;(1-s)^{-7} \\
&=  \frac{1}{6^7} s^7 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^7 (-1)^i \binom{7}{i} s^{6i} \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{7+j-1}{j} s^j
\end{align}$$
by use of the Binomial Theorem.

We have a coefficient of $s^{14}$ in the product whenever $6i + j = 7$ with $0 \le i \le 7$ and $0 \le j$ in the last equation above. There are only two possibilities: $(i,j) = (0,7)$ and $(i,j) = (1,1)$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I like this more than my answer haha! Even if it is the same answer :P

Comment: @awkward, thanks a lot. Yes, didn't consider applying the binomial to the denominator of the geometric series. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the probability generating function here...
However, let me say there is a much simpler way to solve this problem using what are called compositions. In fact, we only need to find the 7-compositions of 14 using the restricted numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$. This happens to have a closed form solution. What this is asking, is that in exactly 7 sums, how can we make the number 14? One way is $(1,1,1,1,1,3,6)$. Another is $(1,1,1,6,1,1,3)$. Another is $(3,2,1,2,3,2,1)$. You will notice there are exactly $7$ elements and they add up to $14$. But for each of these they can be rearranged to with exactly the same numbers in a different order. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

So that is what a composition does. The only thing remaining is the probability, and well if we take 7 rolls, for each way we can get 14 in 7 goes, it is just $(\frac 16)^7$. Or rather there are $6^7$ outcomes when we roll the dice in 7 rolls.

You will find a closed-form solution here:

https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf

Use equation (E) with $n=14$, $k=7$ and $w=6$.

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^j{k \choose j}{n-6j-1 \choose k-1}$$

$$=(-1)^0{7 \choose 0}{14-1 \choose 7-1}+(-1)^1{7 \choose 1}{14-6-1 \choose 7-1}+(-1)^2{7 \choose 2}{14-12-1 \choose 7-1}$$

$$={13 \choose 6}-7{7 \choose 6}=1667$$

So probability of getting 14 in 7 rolls, $P(T=14|R=7)=\frac{1667}{6^7}= 0.005954933$

Does that sound right?

Comment: Super useful to learn about compositions in a formal way. Thanks for the links. I recommend also a reference from wikipedia, namely [where it talks about restricted compositions.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf)

Comment: Yay! I have that link already but thanks! :) Although I can't make head and tail of some expressions... Dude have a look at the question I posted for the bounty haha. Literally killing me with compositions. I have no idea what to do. :P https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795397/random-sum-in-coupon-collection

Comment: I'll attempt to solve it and get back to you in that post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution using only basic knowledge in combinatorics:

We know that the number of possible outcomes of the seven throws of the die is $6^7$ . Now we need to find all outcomes for which the sum of the points, after the seven throws, is 14. It is obvious that each throw would give us at least 1 point. It remains to count the number of ways the other 7 points could be distributed to the throws. For this objective we will use slashes where each slash will separate points which would be distributed to one of the throws.

For example, (··/·//···//·/). Two points will be given to the first throw which will result in an outcome of three points from the first throw, 1 point will be given to the second throw, no points will be given to the third, since there are two consecutive slashes in the row, and etc.

Hence the number of such possible distributions is $\frac{13!}{6!7!}$ . Note that some of these distributions add more than 5 points to one of the throws, so we will have to exclude them from the upper result. Their number is

$ \frac{8!}{6!} - \frac{7!}{6!}=49$.

We subtract $\frac{7!}{6!}$ since we have counted twice the  number of outcomes where the 7 points are distributed into the same throw. Thus the probability that the total number of points is 14 is

$P(A=14)= \frac{1}{6^7} . (\frac{13!}{6!.7!} - 49)$